# Modal doesn't transition into view if another is transitioning out of view

Tags: reactjs, css-transitions, react-hooks

I'm trying to transition a popup in and out of view as it is summoned and dismissed.

Originally rendered as `null`, a click mounts the component hidden and then triggers a transition defined in the CSS to transition the popup into view.

As it mounts, the component registers a click handler on the document and listens for clicks outside of the popup to firstly transition it out of view, and then unmount it completely, removing the event listener as well.

The transitions are triggered by altering my component's `style` attribute, but I've also tried using `className`, which produced the exact same results.

```
import { useRef, useState, useEffect } from 'react'

/*
 * Popup
 *
 * - [x] auto-dismiss on click outside without hogging the click event
 *       (i.e. without using `stopPropagation()`)
 * - [ ] transition into and out of view
 *       ! No transition when opening a popup while another is still transitionning out out view
 */
function Popup ({ dismiss }) {
  const popupRef = useRef(null)
  const [style, setStyle] = useState(hiddenStyles)
  useEffect(() => {
    setStyle(showingStyles)
  }, [])
  useEffect(() => {
    global.document.addEventListener('click', onClickOutside, false)
    return () => {
      global.document.removeEventListener('click', onClickOutside, false)
    }
  }, [])
  function onClickOutside (event) {
    if (!popupRef.current.contains(event.target)) {
      setStyle(hiddenStyles)
      setTimeout(dismiss, 900) // TODO Find better way to dismiss (unmount) popup on animation end (and move this responsibility to the Item?)
    }
  }
  return (
    <div
      className='popup'
      ref={popupRef}
      style={style}
    >
      <style jsx>{`
        .popup {
          z-index: 1;
          color: black;
          background: white;
          border: 1px solid black;
          position: absolute;
          transition: opacity 0.9s ease;
        }
      `}</style>
      <pre>{JSON.stringify(style, null, 2)}</pre>
    </div>
  )
}

/*
 * Popup-producing item
 *
 * - [x] only render popup when wanted, unmount when dismissed
 */
const hiddenStyles = { opacity: 0 }
const showingStyles = { opacity: 1 }
function Item ({ id, body }) {
  const [showActions, setShowActions] = useState(false)

  function openActions () {
    setShowActions(true)
  }

  function hideActions () {
    setShowActions(false)
  }

  return (
    <li className='row' onClick={openActions}>
      <style jsx>{`
        .row {
          position: relative;
          cursor: pointer;
          padding: 5px;
        }
        .row:hover {
          background: #d636e9;
          color: #ffe2f0;
        }
      `}</style>
      {body}
      {showActions
        ? (
          <Popup dismiss={hideActions} />
        ) : null}
    </li>
  )
}
```

When I open the popups individually, taking the time to dismiss one before opening the next, the transitions work. But if I open a popup before another has disappeared completely, the transition gets stuck in its final state from the beginning.

The question is Why?

Answer (score 0):

The stackoverflow snippet tool doesn't support React 16.8, so I refactored my code from hooks to classes and stumbled on a solution while doing so which also works in hook world: replacing

```
useEffect(() => {
    setStyle(showingStyles)
  }, [])
```

with

```
useEffect(() => {
  setTimeout(() => {
    setStyle(showingStyles)
  }, 10)
}, [])
```

I can't show the full functional code using hooks but here the working version using classes:

```js
/*
 * Popup
 *
 * - [x] auto-dismiss on click outside without hogging the click event
 *       (i.e. without using `stopPropagation()`)
 * - [ ] transition into and out of view
 *       ! No transition when opening a popup while another is still transitionning out out view
 */
class Popup extends React.Component {
  constructor (props) {
    super(props)
    this.onClickOutside = this.onClickOutside.bind(this)
    
    this.popupRef = null
    this.state = {
      style: hiddenStyles
    }
  }
  
  componentDidMount () {
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.setState({ style: showingStyles })
    }, 10)
    document.addEventListener('click', this.onClickOutside, false)
  }
  
  componentWillUnmount () {
    document.removeEventListener('click', this.onClickOutside, false)
  }

  onClickOutside (event) {
    if (!this.popupRef.contains(event.target)) {
      this.setState({ style: hiddenStyles })
      setTimeout(this.props.dismiss, 900) // TODO Find better way to dismiss (unmount) popup on animation end (and move this responsibility to the Item?)
    }
  }
  render () {
    return (
      <div
        className='popup'
        ref={(el) => {
          this.popupRef = el
        }}
        style={this.state.style}
      >
        <pre>{JSON.stringify(this.state.style, null, 2)}</pre>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

/*
 * Popup-producing item
 *
 * - [x] only render popup when wanted, unmount when dismissed
 */
const hiddenStyles = { opacity: 0 }
const showingStyles = { opacity: 1 }
class Item extends React.Component {
  constructor (props) {
    super(props)
    this.openActions = this.openActions.bind(this)
    this.hideActions = this.hideActions.bind(this)
    
    this.state = {
      showActions: false
    }
  }

  openActions () {
    this.setState({ showActions: true })
  }

  hideActions () {
    this.setState({ showActions: false })
  }

  render () {
    const { body } = this.props
    return (
      <li className='row' onClick={this.openActions}>
        {body}
        {this.state.showActions
          ? (
            <Popup dismiss={this.hideActions} />
          ) : null}
      </li>
    )
  }
}

/*
 * App
 *
 * - [x] Show list of items
 */
const items = [
  { id: 'a', body: 'Green!' },
  { id: 'b', body: 'Green!' },
  { id: 'c', body: 'Yellow?' },
  { id: 'd', body: 'Red' },
  { id: 'e', body: 'Gray' }
]
class App extends React.Component {
  render () {
    return (
      <ul>
        {items.map((item) => {
          return <Item {...item} key={item.id} />
        })}
      </ul>
    )
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('app'))
```

```css
.row {
  position: relative;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 5px;
}
.row:hover {
  background: #d636e9;
  color: #ffe2f0;
}
.popup {
  z-index: 1;
  color: black;
  background: white;
  border: 1px solid black;
  position: absolute;
  transition: opacity 0.9s ease;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="app" />
```

I don't like this solution at all because I don't understand why the `setTimeout` is needed but at least it works...